# CSS glitch effect triggered by hover not working

Tags: html, css, import, hyperlink, tags

So I have done a simple copy and paste of this 'glitch text' effect from Codepen. It was in SCSS from Codepen but this code has now been changed to css, a developer friend of mine made some syntax adjustments. It uses CSS animation. Yet the animation still doesn't work properly. I have no idea what's going on?

The animation would be triggered by a hover motion from the cursor. So I think once I can fix its ability to respond to the cursor's hover, it should work. Currently, when I 'hover' over the text to trigger the animation, the cursor turns from an arrow into an i-cursor, as if about to type something.

Essentially...the 'hover' of the cursor isn't activating the animation. And the animation can't be triggered without this.

Here is the html:

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="author" content="team" />
  <title>Unnamed Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="glitch2.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sounds.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/iyx6mdm.css" />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

</head>

<body>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="second_page.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="glitch.html">Glitch</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="bg">

<div class="text-style">
<div class="glitch-text">'11:11'</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the css:

```
    *, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
outline: none;
}

.text-style {
font-family: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1.5;
color: white;
}

.bg {
position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100vh;
background-color: black;
}

.glitch-text {
font-size: 200px;
}

.glitch-text:hover:before,.glitch-text:hover:after {
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: -1;
}

.glitch-text:hover:before {
top: 49.5%;
left: 49.5%;
color: rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.8);
animation: distort1 300ms linear infinite;
}

.glitch-text:hover:after {
top: 50.5%;
left: 50.5%;
color: rgba(0, 1, 0, );
animation: distort2 300ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes distort1 {
0% {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 49.5%;
}

12.5% {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 50%;
}

  25% {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 50.5%;
}

  37.5% {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50.5%;
}

  50% {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 50.5%;
}

  62.5% {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 50%;
}

  75% {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 49.5%;
}

  87.5% {
  top: 50%;
  left: 49.5%;
}

  100% {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 49.5%;
}

}

@keyframes distort2 {
  0% {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 50.5%;
}

  12.5% {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50.5%;
}

  25% {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 50.5%;
}

  37.5% {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 50%;
}

  50% {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 49.5%;
}

  62.5% {
  top: 50%;
  left: 49.5%;
}

  75% {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 49.5%;
}

  87.5% {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 50%;
}

  100% {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 50.5%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that were causing your undesired behavior:

1. No `content` was set for the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, meaning they would not render. From the description of the effect, I presume that the `content` property of both should be `'11:11'`.
2. The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements even if they had `content`, they would render behind the black background of the `.bg` element, meaning they would not be visible. There are several options to rectify this, including:

   1. Make `.bg` a stacking context element, such as by applying a non-`auto` `z-index` value (I did this below).
   2. Increase the `z-index` of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements such they would render higher in the stacking order than the `.bg` element.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

.text-style {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white;
}

.bg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.glitch-text {
  font-size: 200px;
}

.glitch-text:hover:before,
.glitch-text:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
  content: "'11:11'";
}

.glitch-text:hover:before {
  top: 49.5%;
  left: 49.5%;
  color: rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.8);
  animation: distort1 300ms linear infinite;
}

.glitch-text:hover:after {
  top: 50.5%;
  left: 50.5%;
  color: rgba(0, 1, 0, );
  animation: distort2 300ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes distort1 {
  0% {
    top: 49.5%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }
  12.5% {
    top: 49.5%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  25% {
    top: 49.5%;
    left: 50.5%;
  }
  37.5% {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50.5%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 50.5%;
  }
  62.5% {
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }
  87.5% {
    top: 50%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 49.5%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }
}

@keyframes distort2 {
  0% {
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 50.5%;
  }
  12.5% {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50.5%;
  }
  25% {
    top: 49.5%;
    left: 50.5%;
  }
  37.5% {
    top: 49.5%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 49.5%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }
  62.5% {
    top: 50%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }
  75% {
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 49.5%;
  }
  87.5% {
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50.5%;
    left: 50.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/iyx6mdm.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="second_page.html">About</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="glitch.html">Glitch</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="bg">
  <div class="text-style">
    <div class="glitch-text">'11:11'</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. The animation does now work, however it seems to be activated by hovering over any part of the full page. It no longer only works when hovering over text. I would like to make it so that it only works when hovering over the text.

Comment: If the window is sufficiently small, then the bounding box of the text that the browser would be considered hovered would be the same as the the black background. Consider increasing the size of the window and it you should see that the hover effect does not activate unless hovering over the bounding box of the text.

Comment: Actually, I have now solved this. Don't worry. Thanks again Wongjn :)